# Do the moderators/SE employees have some type of private communication channel?

Tags: support, chat, moderators, email, private-messaging

Do the moderators/SE employees have some type of private communication channel?
If yes, how does it work? Is it a private chat? Or a mailing list?

Comment: There is the Teacher's Lounge afaik, which is a moderator chat room.

Comment: By all accounts they use [smoke signals generated by a green grass on a fire and a horse blanket](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Frederic_Remington_smoke_signal.jpg/800px-Frederic_Remington_smoke_signal.jpg).

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are giving away all of our secrets.

Comment: They make blankets out of horses @MartijnPieters? It's an outrage!

Comment: @Bart It's ok. Horses aren't real unicorns, so they can't feel any pain.

Comment: An illustration of the Teachers' Lounge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDRrE.png

Comment: It's here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly

Comment: They are all sewn together into a Great Nazi Monkey Moderator Centipede.  I was in between @BilltheLizard and Andrew Barber.  It was not pleasant, but the communication (and other) lines were kept open.

Comment: My therapist sends his regards @Won't.

Answer (score 17):

Moderators and employees have private chat rooms (that are invite only).

There are a few such private rooms around - most sites have a specific mod only chat or two, and there is also a room for mods of all sites.

---

And of course there is email - employees have access to email addresses of moderators and users, so if needed these can be used.

Comment: "employees have access to email addresses" -- wow, we really are a high-tech company!

Comment: And you probably have weird usernames so that earthlings cannot guess what your real email address is?

Comment: @Oded Do moderators have access to email addresses as well?

Comment: @Fra - moderators don't. Some staff do.